# transferFrom result in execution reverted: Insufficient allowance

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I am trying to make working the `transferFrom` process.
I follow the steps who are :

1. `approve(address spender, uint256 amount)` -> returning **1** so it is working
2. `transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount)` -> returning an error message : execution reverted: Insufficient allowance

I can confirm you that I have enough ETH in the two wallets to pay gas fees.
I try to call allowance function but returning me **0**...

If I call the **balanceOf** method of 0xbe71b68f1cbe13561ab882f590fa91c6d79dd193, I got in return : 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000056bc75e2d63100000 = 100000000000000000000

Please find the parameters for the two functions :

- The main wallet from which I would like to manage funds of my sub wallet :
  0xe08b7d9464193616cb97086744caf8cae06a73c3
- The sub wallet : 0xbe71b68f1cbe13561ab882f590fa91c6d79dd193
  Wallets are working on Rinkeby Test Network.

**approve :**

- Address : 0xe08b7d9464193616cb97086744caf8cae06a73c3
- Unit256 : 100000000000000000000000

**transferFrom :**

- Address : 0xbe71b68f1cbe13561ab882f590fa91c6d79dd193
- Address : 0xe08b7d9464193616cb97086744caf8cae06a73c3
- Unit256 : 100000000000000000000

**This is the params send for each requests :**

**approve** :

```
"params": [
        {
            "from": "0xbe71b68f1cbe13561ab882f590fa91c6d79dd193",
            "to": "0xd9ba894e0097f8cc2bbc9d24d308b98e36dc6d02",
            "data": "0x095ea7b3000000000000000000000000e08b7d9464193616cb97086744caf8cae06a73c300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000152d02c7e14af6800000"
        },
        "latest"
    ]
```

**transferFrom** :

```
"params": [
        {
            "from": "0xe08b7d9464193616cb97086744caf8cae06a73c3",
            "to": "0xd9ba894e0097f8cc2bbc9d24d308b98e36dc6d02",
            "data": "0x23b872dd000000000000000000000000be71b68f1cbe13561ab882f590fa91c6d79dd193000000000000000000000000e08b7d9464193616cb97086744caf8cae06a73c30000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008ac7230489e80000"
        },
        "latest"
    ]
```

So that's why I'm asking you some help on this, the approve call is working properly but not the transferFrom, and I don't know why...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my error, I send the approve with "eth_call" instead of "eth_sendTransaction" method with my RPC server...

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem like the `approve` worked fine.

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xd9ba894e0097f8cc2bbc9d24d308b98e36dc6d02#readContract

In the screenshot below we can see that the address `0xbe71b68f1cbe13561ab882f590fa91c6d79dd193` balance is `100000000000000000000`.

But when calling the `allowance` method to check how much balance the `0xbe71b68f1cbe13561ab882f590fa91c6d79dd193` address is allowing `0xe08b7d9464193616cb97086744caf8cae06a73c3` to spend, we see 0:

[image]

Check and make sure to `approve` it correctly.

You can try doing it manually from here to test: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xd9ba894e0097f8cc2bbc9d24d308b98e36dc6d02#writeContract